# Cocoa and OpenGL: failed to draw cube

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, glut, osx-mountain-lion

I am making a simple app in which I should draw a cube with GLUT.
Since I've studied OpenGL with plain C, I have difficulty to understand what functions should I call to initialize the context, since I don't have to call anymore functions like glutInit and others.
So I subclassed NSOpenGLView, disabled one shot memory for the window and wrote this code:

```
@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSOpenGLContext* context=[self openGLContext];
        [context makeCurrentContext];
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 1000);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 0);
    glutSolidCube(10);

    glFlush();
}
```

But it seems like I'm missing something because I see the black view but not the cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the code in initWithFrame to prepareGL. E.g.

```
- (void)prepareOpenGL {
    NSOpenGLContext *context = [self openGLContext];
    [context makeCurrentContext];
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 1000);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say: it's already in the initWithFrame method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it needs to be in the method called prepareOpenGL

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I misunderstood. Nice answer, that solved the problem.